# Going backwards by one in file stream

Tags: c, pointers, filestream, encryption

Say I have a file pointer like this:

```
file_ptr = fopen(“test.txt”, “r+”);
```

and I want to change each `char`'s ASCII value as I move through the stream (I am doing this as a cipher, so if there is a better or more efficient way to do this, please let me know).

I am trying to use a `while(!feof(file_ptr)) {}` loop with `fgetc()` and `fputc`, but the `file_ptr` will be pointing to the next char, so i want to know if there is something i can do point it backwards one spot.

Essentially, I want to know the file stream equivalent for:

```
char* blah="blah blah";
char* index=blah;
index++;/*how to navigate a file stream in this way*/
```

Comment: `fseek(file_ptr, -1, SEEK_CUR);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes: you can use [the `fseek` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/fseek.html):

```
fseek(file_ptr, -1L, SEEK_CUR); // move backwards one character
```

Furthermore, after your `fputc` and before your `fgetc`, you'll want to call `fseek` again:

```
fseek(file_ptr, 0L, SEEK_CUR); // don't move
```

just to notify the system that you're switching between reads and writes, so that it knows to properly flush all buffers and whatnot. (Otherwise you might not actually be where you think.)

By the way, for this to work properly, you'll want to open the file in binary mode rather than text mode:

```
file_ptr = fopen("test.txt", "rb+");
```

since otherwise the within-C definition of "character" might not exactly match the inside-the-file definition of "character" (especially when it comes to line endings), and `fseek` might put you in the middle of one of the latter.

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have known to notify the system like that...also, what is the purpose of the "L" in the offset parameter?

Comment: @spatara: No purpose, really. That just makes it a `long`, but if you write `-1`, the compiler will implicitly convert it to a `long` anyway (because it's being passed to a function that's declared as taking a `long`). Either one is 100% fine.