# Going backward in a file in c

Tags: c, file, file-io

I have file and it contents name, surname and age.

> john doe 20
>
> lionel messi 33
>
> cristiano ronaldo 35

What I want to do is to get specific person by his/her age and updating any information of him/her. In the sample code below, I want to find a person by his/her age change it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    char line[30];
    FILE *fp;
    int age;
    if (!(fp = fopen("test.txt", "rb"))) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return;
    }
    char name[20], surname[20];
    
    while (fgets (line, 30, fp)) {
        int off = 0;
        while (sscanf (line, "%s%s%d%n", name, surname, &age, &off) == 3) {
            if(age == 35) {
                fseek(fp,-2, SEEK_CUR);
                printf("%s", name);
                fprintf(fp, "%d", 19);
            }
            strcpy(line, line+off);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

However, my code does not work as expected. Sometimes it updates the information but sometimes not. In addition, I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549652/going-backwards-by-one-in-file-stream) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954642/unable-to-use-fseek-in-backward-direction-from-the-current-position) links to create this program.
Thx in advance for your helpful comments.

Comment: Use fopen with "rb+" to open for both reading and writing.

Comment: If you're reading the file with fgets(), that indicates it's a line-based file with variable-sized records. Doing random-access reads and writes on such a file is not possible. Applications that use such files generally read the whole file into memory, make changes in memory, the re-write the whole file.

Comment: Note that the `%n` is going to give you information about the `sscanf` which is not directly related to the position in the file.  But, more importantly, you've already read the newline with `fgets`, so the `-2` in the seek goes back to the 5, not the 3.  (It backs up over the newline and the 5, not the 5 and the 3).

Comment: Ah, I just realized what you're doing with the offset.  Ick.  You should restructure the loops entirely, but certainly don't use `strcpy` here.  Do something like `char buf[30]; char *line = buf; ... line += off;`.  Moving data around like you're doing is a tragedy.